# Is it possible to check if a group rank changes using roblox script

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a system when it alerts a player whenever they're promoted in a group. I've poked around with groupservice but it doesn't have any system for rank change checking

Is this possible? And if it is, how would I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't any in-game signals, nor any webhooks to observe.

Furthermore, if you try to long poll the [Player:GetRankInGroup](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/GetRankInGroup) or [Player:GetRoleInGroup](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/GetRoleInGroup) functions, you'll get the same result as the first time you call it. The docs have this note :

> If you make multiple calls of GetRankInGroup/GetRoleInGroup on the same player with the same group ID will yield the same result as when the method was first called with the given group ID. The caching behavior is on a per-peer basis: a server does not share the same cache as a client.

So unless you're going to host and implement a custom web service, there doesn't appear to be a supported way to detect the change.

Comment: Thanks Kylaaa, I know just how I can do that.

Comment: @Cmb, take a look at the [group APIs](https://groups.roblox.com/docs#!/Groups/get_v2_users_userId_groups_roles), you may be able to long poll the endpoint directly.